# Geometry Nodes align

Tags: objects, transforms, normals, geometry-nodes

How can I align a Cylinder with the normals of the surface? I want it to be aligned with the points on the surface as well.

[image]

Comment: I edited my answer. Apart from placing the nodes in the wrong order, your general idea seems to he correct, it's just that the _Align Rotation to Vector_ node doesn't use the normal attribute (yet?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE: The answer below is for Blender 2.92, in the experimental build 2.93.0 Alpha this already works. Keep the nodes in the order described down here. Set *Vector* to *Attribute* and enter the value vertex_normal (or choose it from the dropdown menu).

For Blender 2.92: Not the answer to get it working (because it doesn't in this or older versions), jut a quick explanation of how to setup the nodes and what they do.

The *Align Rotation to Vector* node rotates the points of the plane object according to values you enter in there (if *Vector* option set to *Vector* instead of *Attribute*). Which means, you have to put it before the *Point Instance* node to have an effect on the rotation of the instanced objects.

However, this only rotates all points into the same direction for X/Y/Z given by the three values entered there (all set to 0 would mean, the rotation isn't changed at all).

So *Attribute* must be the option to choose I guess - and this is the point where someone should take over who knows how to get the vertex normals. I don't know and can't find a list which attribute names Blender understands, but in my opinion the attribute which gets the vertex normal must be put in there and it should work as you want it.

I just watched a Youtube video on geometry nodes and talking about the attributes it was mentioned that the normal attribute is still a work in progress and yet only used by the *Point Distribution* node.

Comment: Typing in "normal" as the attribute works for me for the *Align Rotation to Vector* node

Comment: How? It doesn't do what is desired to do, you could only align all instances in the same direction. If you've got a working solution, please add it as an answer here.

Comment: My apologies I mistook what you said about the *Point Distribution* node.

Comment: That's a pity, I was hoping there is a solution to this...

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hey. Trying to follow the instructions but the list of attribute names is just empty for me. What could be wrong?

Comment: It looks like "Point Instance" node deletes all attributes from the input geometry.

Comment: Which version you're using? It's not yet working in 2.92, you have to get 2.93 Alpha.

Comment: and of course blender GNs has completely changed in 3.0 so you can no longer choose Attribute!!!  sigh

Comment: @james_t Well, that's how it goes. Not all answers on this site can stay valid or relevant forever...